# InvocationTargetException in DialogFragment & NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-inflate, numberpicker

I'm trying to show a NumberPicker in a dialog in order to let the user select a value between 0 and 10. It's my second day spent trying to make it work.

This is what I have:

- fragment_number_picker (layout):

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/numberPickerFragmentLinearLayout"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <NumberPicker
         android:id="@+id/numberPickerInFragment"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="48dp"
         android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
  ```
- DialogFragment definition:

  ```
  public class NumberPickerCustomDialog extends DialogFragment {
  Context context;
  public NumberPickerCustomDialog() {}

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
      LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)     
          context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
      View view = li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_number_picker, null);

      builder
      // Set view:
         .setView(view)
      // Add action buttons
         .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     // Accept number
              }
           })
         .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  dialog.dismiss();
              }
          });   

     NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerInFragment);
     np.setMaxValue(200);
     np.setMinValue(0);

     np.setFocusable(true);
     np.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

     return builder.create();
     }
  }
  ```
- Call from the main Activity:

  ```
  public void openNumberPicker(){
       FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
       NumberPickerCustomDialog npc = new NumberPickerCustomDialog();
       npc.show(fm, "fragment_number_picker");
  }
  ```

I'm getting an InvocationTargetException and I can't make it work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the context you're using:

```
context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Instead, you need the activity's own context:

```
context = getActivity();
```